# i can't use oauth 2.0 to connect with my server using android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

i'm new with android and i need to do a connection with server with oauth 2.0 i looked in internet and found just example how to dowit with google or github but my need is to  connect with my own server i have the  clientId clientSecret and the scope all i need is  to get the token correctly
i hope my question is clear
thank you 
this what i have donne

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(Authentification.this);
            Bundle options = new Bundle();
            options.putSerializable("numero", numero);
            
            am.getAuthToken(
                    null,
                    "whrite",
                    options,
                    this,
                    new OnTokenAcquired(),
                    null);

private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
    @Override
    public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
        // Get the result of the operation from the AccountManagerFuture.
        try{
            Bundle bundle = result.getResult();

            // The token is a named value in the bundle. The name of the value
            // is stored in the constant AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN.
            String token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
    System.out.println("================>>>>"+token);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the AppAuth code sample. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/android-setup)
has step by step instructions on how to run it.

Once it is working reconfigure it to point to your own Authorization Server.